Flatten noise floor of spectrum by reference/dark measurement
I'm currently stuck with a problem and would appreciate any input or guidance in this regard.
Background information
In a laser experiment, an amplitude signal in volts and a position signal are acquired simultaneously by data acquisition. The signal bandwidth is in the range of a few kHz. The position signal is later converted to a delay "light time", i.e. the time scale is converted from laboratory time to picosecond time, allowing to observe a single-cycle THz pulse. To increase the SNR, multiple traces are acquired and averaged, which works well.
However, the system has some systematic/repeatable errors, such as position-dependent offsets in amplitude. See the left column in Fig.1 below. The first subplot from the top shows the light trace and the dark trace. The second subplot from the top is a zoom-in and shows the position-dependent offsets in amplitude. To compensate for these errors, a "dark" trace is recorded without any THz pulse, which captures the background signal well. When the time domain signal is windowed and converted by an FFT, the dark traces show two major concerns: a large amplitude increase at low frequencies and a roll-off at higher frequencies. This is shown in the last plot below in the left column.
The first problem can be completely compensated by subtracting the light trace from the single dark trace in the time domain, as it is shown in the right column of Fig.1. The two dark traces can also be subtracted from each other, eliminating any repeatable pattern. This approach helps to flatten the noise floor at low frequencies. However, the roll-off at higher frequencies is present in both the light and dark traces and is not compensated.

I suspect that this comes from the DAQ, or more precisely from the necessary low-pass filter in front of the ADC to prevent aliasing. The limited bandwidth of the photodetector used to obtain the signal could also cause this roll-off.
Main question:
Is there a way to "straighten" the noise floor at higher frequencies? I would assume that the dark trace would be an ideal candidate for this.
My attempt to solve this problem
When taking the complex signal from the FFT and using the absolute square and then subtracting it, the roll-off at higher frequencies persists and the semilogy module of matplotlib in Python has problems displaying the data because some of the data points are now below 0.

By using 10*np.log10(np.abs(...)**2)) and then subtracting the light data minus the dark data, I can get a flat noise floor. However, this approach is still wrong because the logarithm is a nonlinear function and small amplitudes are weighted the same as large amplitudes, making the high amplitudes "spikey" due to the noise of the dark trace, which was originally very small.

Research
If I understand the problem correctly, the roll-off looks like a low-pass filter. If the inverse/reverse of a low-pass filter were applied, the spectrum would be straight again.
I found the following questions about this problem on StackExchange:

How to design an inverse for a Butterworth low-pass filter?
Find reverse one pole lowpass filter
Invertible low-pass (Butterworth) filter in python (scipy)?

It seems that inverting a low pass filter is not straightforward and may introduce oscillations or other artifacts.
Also, I first have to find the right coefficients by curve-fitting (?) the dark trace in the frequency domain, then invert the filter and apply it to the dark and light traces.
Is there another way to flatten the spectrum without going the way of an inverse low pass filter and having the dark trace as additional information?
The averaged data with light time, and the amplitude of Light - Dark1 as well as Dark1 - Dark2 is uploaded here:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3x76n2bdi416e3kcim13b/data.csv?rlkey=kb6ctkmw2ij66hm5viwl1kucg&st=bxgzmiws&dl=0
The minimum working example to load and plot the data in Python is here:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import EngFormatter

def calc_fft(time, signal):
    dt = (time[-1] - time[0]) / (len(time) - 1)
    frequency = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(time), dt)
    signal_fft = np.fft.rfft(signal)
    return frequency, signal_fft

_, light_time, light, dark = np.loadtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",", skiprows=1, unpack=True)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
ax=axs[0]
ax.plot(light_time, dark, color="black", alpha=0.8, label="Dark")
ax.plot(light_time, light, color="tab:orange", label="Light")
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("s"))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("V"))
ax.legend()

_, dark_fft = calc_fft(light_time, dark)
frequency, light_fft = calc_fft(light_time, light)

min_THz_frequency =  0.1e12
max_THz_frequency = 10.0e12
filter_frequency = (frequency >= min_THz_frequency) & (frequency <= max_THz_frequency)

ax=axs[1]
ax.semilogy(frequency[filter_frequency], np.abs(dark_fft[filter_frequency])**2, color="black", alpha=0.8, label="Dark")
ax.semilogy(frequency[filter_frequency], np.abs(light_fft[filter_frequency])**2, color="tab:orange", label="Light")
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")
ax.set_ylabel("Power spectrum |V²|")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("Hz"))
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

I would mainly be interested if there is a straight-forward numerical way to "equalize" the gain according to the dark trace. Maybe I can't see the forest for the trees. I would appreciate any help.

Although I like the numerical inversion of the dark trace to equalize the amplitude in the spectrum, the dark trace has too much "high frequency" noise. This reminded me of an article I read,
https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1159.php
which discusses the difference between vector and RMS averaging. Fortunately, I have a set of measurement data and averaged in the time domain, as is common in the field I'm working in. The goal is to reduce the noise before applying any nonlinear function, resulting in a higher SNR in the frequency domain/lowering the noise floor by averaging.
By computing the FFT for each individual trace, taking the magnitude of those individual traces in frequency domain, and averaging them, the noise floor is not pushed down, but smoothed.
It turns out that this property is ideal for creating an (inverted) gain function.
If anyone wants to recreate the plots, I have uploaded the dataset with single traces for light and dark traces here:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/n31qbl9c37wrqsmcevwwf/data_single_traces.zip?rlkey=9c5g9cuzu8uzskxwaovl9wc60&st=s7x3acl5&dl=0
In the following plot, I don't restrict the bandwidth, but show the full frequency spectrum. The black/orange traces are obtained by averaging in the time domain and taking the FFT of that average.
The gray/blue trace uses the method described above, only averaging the absolute value of each trace after applying the FFT. The gray trace gives a good estimate of the shape of the noise floor, it just has an offset compared to the black trace obtained by vector averaging. However, this offset is eliminated anyway because the gain curve is normalized to the peak of the dark trace.

This results in a flat noise floor and works with light and dark traces obtained by vector averaging. I like this solution because my first idea to somehow filter out the high noise of the dark trace would probably have required a “magic number” that would only fit this data set. But since I just used a different method of averaging, I hope it can be used in many applications without being too specific.

The main problem, that the amplitude of the light trace was affected, also seems to be solved.
For comparison, the right subplot shows the original light trace in blue, just shifted up to overlap with the new light trace multiplied by the smooth gain. The amplitude is not affected, but the noise floor is flat. The gray trace also shows the same noise profile as the black trace. In the time domain, there is also little difference between blue and orange, showing that this method seems to work.

The code to recreate the figures with the dataset from above is here:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import EngFormatter


def calc_fft(time, signal):
    dt = (time[-1] - time[0]) / (len(time) - 1)
    frequency = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(time), dt)
    signal_fft = np.fft.rfft(signal)
    return frequency, signal_fft


light_time = np.loadtxt("light_time.csv", delimiter=",")
dark = np.loadtxt("dark_single_traces.csv", delimiter=",")
light = np.loadtxt("light_single_traces.csv", delimiter=",")

# Fig.1

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(26 / 2.54, 12 / 2.54))
ax = axs[0]
ax.plot(light_time, np.mean(dark, axis=1), color="black", alpha=0.8, label="Dark")
ax.plot(light_time, np.mean(light, axis=1), color="tab:orange", label="Light")
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("s"))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("V"))
ax.legend()

_, dark_fft = calc_fft(light_time,  np.mean(dark, axis=1))
frequency, light_fft = calc_fft(light_time, np.mean(light, axis=1))

min_THz_frequency = 0.1e12
max_THz_frequency = 10.0e12
filter_frequency = (frequency >= min_THz_frequency) & (frequency <= max_THz_frequency)

ax = axs[1]
ax.semilogy(frequency[filter_frequency], np.abs(dark_fft[filter_frequency]) ** 2, color="black", alpha=0.8,
            label="Dark")
ax.semilogy(frequency[filter_frequency], np.abs(light_fft[filter_frequency]) ** 2, color="tab:orange", label="Light")
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")
ax.set_ylabel("Power spectrum |V²|")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("Hz"))
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()

# Fig.2

fig2, axs2 = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(26 / 2.54, 12 / 2.54))
ax = axs2[1]
max_amplitude = np.max(np.abs(light_fft))
gain = max_amplitude / np.abs(dark_fft)

ax.semilogy(frequency[filter_frequency], (gain[filter_frequency] * np.abs(dark_fft[filter_frequency])) ** 2, color="black", alpha=0.8,
            label=r"Dark $\cdot$ inverse gain of dark")
ax.semilogy(frequency[filter_frequency], 1e8*(np.abs(light_fft[filter_frequency])) ** 2, color="tab:blue", label=r"Light $\cdot 10^8$")
ax.semilogy(frequency[filter_frequency], (gain[filter_frequency] * np.abs(light_fft[filter_frequency])) ** 2, color="tab:orange", label=r"Light $\cdot$ inverse gain of dark")
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")
ax.set_ylabel("Power spectrum |V²|")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("Hz"))
ax.legend(loc="upper right")

ax = axs2[0]

dark_irfft = np.fft.irfft(gain * dark_fft)
light_ifft = np.fft.irfft(gain * light_fft)

ax.plot(light_time, dark_irfft, color="black", alpha=0.8, label="Dark")
ax.plot(light_time, light_ifft, color="tab:orange", label="Light")
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("s"))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("V"))
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()

# Fig.3

fig3, axs3 = plt.subplots(figsize=(26 / 2.54, 12 / 2.54))
dark_fft_single_traces = np.fft.rfft(dark, axis=0).T
dark_fft_smooth = np.mean(np.abs(dark_fft_single_traces.T), axis=1)

light_fft_single_traces = np.fft.rfft(light, axis=0).T
light_fft_smooth = np.mean(np.abs(light_fft_single_traces.T), axis=1)

ax = axs3
ax.semilogy(frequency, np.abs(dark_fft)**2, color="black", alpha=0.8, label="Dark, average in time domain")
ax.semilogy(frequency, np.abs(dark_fft_smooth)**2, color="grey", alpha=0.8, label="Dark, absolute average in freq domain")

ax.semilogy(frequency, np.abs(light_fft)**2, color="tab:orange", alpha=0.8, label="Light, average in time domain")
ax.semilogy(frequency, np.abs(light_fft_smooth)**2, color="tab:blue", alpha=0.8, label="Light, absolute average in freq domain")

ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")
ax.set_ylabel("Power spectrum |V²|")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("Hz"))
ax.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.tight_layout()

# Fig.4

fig4, axs4 = plt.subplots(figsize=(26 / 2.54, 12 / 2.54))
ax = axs4

smooth_gain = np.max(dark_fft_smooth) / dark_fft_smooth

ax.semilogy(frequency, (smooth_gain * np.abs(dark_fft))**2, color="black", alpha=0.8, label=r"Dark, avg. in time domain $\cdot$ smooth gain")
ax.semilogy(frequency, (smooth_gain * np.abs(dark_fft_smooth))**2, color="grey", alpha=0.8, label=r"Dark, abs. avg. in freq domain $\cdot$ smooth gain")

ax.semilogy(frequency, (smooth_gain * np.abs(light_fft))**2, color="tab:orange", alpha=0.8, label=r"Light, avg. in time domain $\cdot$ smooth gain")
#ax.semilogy(frequency, (smooth_gain * np.abs(light_fft_smooth))**2, color="tab:blue", alpha=0.8, label="Light, absolute average in freq domain")

ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")
ax.set_ylabel("Power spectrum |V²|")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("Hz"))
ax.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.tight_layout()

# Fig. 5

fig5, axs5 = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(26 / 2.54, 12 / 2.54))
ax = axs5[1]
ax.semilogy(frequency[filter_frequency], 1e3 * (np.abs(dark_fft[filter_frequency])) ** 2, color="black", alpha=0.8, label=r"Dark $\cdot$ 1e3")
ax.semilogy(frequency[filter_frequency], (smooth_gain[filter_frequency] * np.abs(dark_fft[filter_frequency])) ** 2, color="grey", alpha=0.8,
            label=r"Dark $\cdot$ smooth gain")

ax.semilogy(frequency[filter_frequency], 1e3 * (np.abs(light_fft[filter_frequency])) ** 2, color="tab:blue", label=r"Light $\cdot$ 1e3")
ax.semilogy(frequency[filter_frequency], (smooth_gain[filter_frequency] * np.abs(light_fft[filter_frequency])) ** 2, color="tab:orange", label=r"Light $\cdot$ smooth gain")
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")
ax.set_ylabel("Power spectrum |V²|")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("Hz"))
ax.legend(loc="upper right")

ax = axs5[0]

dark_irfft = np.fft.irfft(smooth_gain * dark_fft)
light_ifft = np.fft.irfft(smooth_gain * light_fft)

ax.plot(light_time, np.mean(dark, axis=1)/ np.max(np.mean(light, axis=1)), color="black", alpha=0.8, label="Dark")
ax.plot(light_time, dark_irfft / np.max(light_ifft), color="grey", alpha=0.8, label=r"Dark $\cdot$ smooth gain")

ax.plot(light_time, np.mean(light, axis=1) / np.max(np.mean(light, axis=1)), color="tab:blue", label="Light")
ax.plot(light_time, light_ifft / np.max(light_ifft), color="tab:orange", label=r"Light $\cdot$ smooth gain")

ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude (norm. to light peak)")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter("s"))
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Nice use of application knowledge. The one comment I'd make is that whilst our approaches adjust the amplitude, they do nothing to the phase, thus will not undo the effect of any analog filtering. Therefore, I'd probably contact the data acquisition manufacturer and ask for specifics on the low pass anti-aliasing filter used. You can then compute the frequency response and trivially undo the effect of the filtering. I'll add this to my answer to demonstrate.

A straight-forward numerical way to equalise the amplitudes of the frequency components is to simply normalise them as desired once data is acquired. Below is some Matlab code that demonstrates this using the data you uploaded, which hopefully you can easily port to Python and adapt as required (e.g. restrict to specific frequency bands, etc):
% load data
data = csvread('data.csv',1,0);
light_time = data(:,2);
light = data(:,3);
dark = data(:,4);

% transform to frequency domain
fft_dark = fft(dark);
fft_light = fft(light);
sample_interval = (light_time(end)-light_time(1))/(numel(dark)-1);
frequencies = (0:numel(dark)-1)/numel(dark)/sample_interval;

% work out the gain necessary to equalise amplitudes to the arbitrarily
% chosen maximum amplitude
max_amplitude = max(abs(fft_dark));
gain = max_amplitude ./ abs(fft_dark);

% transform equalised signal to the time domain
equalised_dark = ifft(fft_dark.*gain);
equalised_light = ifft(fft_light.*gain);

% visualise results
subplot(3,1,1); plot(frequencies/10^12, abs([fft_dark.*gain, fft_dark])/numel(dark)*1e6); xlabel('Frequency (THz)'); ylabel('Amplitude (µV)'); legend({'equalised dark','dark'},'location','south')
subplot(3,1,2); plot(light_time*10^12, [equalised_dark, dark]*1e6); xlabel('Time (ps)'); ylabel('Amplitude (µV)'); legend({'equalised dark','dark'})
subplot(3,1,3); plot(light_time*10^12, [equalised_light, light]*1e6); xlabel('Time (ps)'); ylabel('Amplitude (µV)'); legend({'equalised light','light'})

The resulting output for the data you uploaded is shown in the figures below. The frequencies this mainly amplifies are beyond your signal bandwidth, thus are dominated by noise, hence it is anticipated to degrade your signal-to-noise ratio, which indeed appears to be consistent with what is observed in the plots.

Update
The one aspect to bear in mind is that whilst these approaches of scaling the amplitude can undo the effect of filter gain, they won't undo the effect of the filter phase shift. Therefore, I'd recommend contacting the equipment manufacturer and asking for specifics on any filtering used so that you can compute its frequency response, $H$, and divide the fft of the filter output, $y$, by that, which is effectively deconvolving the filter out of the filter output to obtain the filter input, $x$:
$$x\left[n\right]=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{\frac{\mathcal{F}\left\{y\left[n\right]\right\}}{H\left[\omega\right]}\right\}$$
Where $n$ is the sample number, and $\omega$ is the frequency (rad/s) equal to the set used in the fft.
This is in contrast to my originally proposed answer, which conceptually was:
$$x\left[n\right]\approx\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left\{\frac{\mathcal{F}\left\{y\left[n\right]\right\}}{|H\left[\omega\right]|}\right\}$$

Thanks for the quick reply and for pointing me in the right direction. I could reproduce your plots in Matlab.
Unfortunately, similar to the result in Fig. 3 above, the dark trace itself contains high-frequency noise that passes through the gain and causes large amplitude fluctuations in the light trace. In this plot, I have shifted the original light trace (blue) up to show how the amplitude (orange) has been affected by the gain based on the dark trace.
However, I found another way, which I think deserves a separate answer, but can be combined with this answer if it is more appropriate.

By all means, post your own separate answer as an alternative idea.
